# requireJs: dependencies not getting loaded for jsep

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs

This is my config

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : 'vassets/lib/',
    shim : {
        'knockout' : [ 'jquery' ]
    },
    paths : {
        jquery : 'jquery/jquery.min',
        knockout : 'knockout/knockout',
        selectize : 'selectize.js/js/standalone/selectize.min',
        main : '/vassets/js/koapp/main',
        jsep : '/vassets/js/jsep/jsep.min'
    }
});
```

jsep is the javascript expression parser that is available here http://jsep.from.so/

This is my module definition:

```
define ()->
     require ['jsep'],(jsep)->
        console.log jsep
        # does not work, jsep is undefined

     ()->
        console.log jsep
        # does not work, jsep is available. but HOW????
        # I dont see this type of usage in api documnentation. How does this work?
```

In addition the following module definition also does not work

```
   define ['jsep'], (jsep)->
     console.log jsep
     # does not work
     # this is the normal usage I find in documentation, why this does not work???
```

Could

Comment: possible duplicate of [RequireJS module's dependencies not being evaluated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953585/requirejs-modules-dependencies-not-being-evaluated)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks. It was ofcourse duplicate. But I did not know what to look for. I have a minimum working example, why the rage to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the shim, resolved the issue. for modules that do not implement define function, as required by require js. There is exports config that is required in the shim config. The below configuration made it work.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : 'vassets/lib/',
    shim : {
        'knockout' : [ 'jquery' ],
    'jsep': {
      exports: 'jsep'
    }
    },
    paths : {
        jquery : 'jquery/jquery.min',
        knockout : 'knockout/knockout',
        selectize : 'selectize.js/js/standalone/selectize.min',
        main : '/vassets/js/koapp/main',
        jsep : '/vassets/js/jsep/jsep.min'
    }
});
```